# Nav Mesh Agent の重ね合わせ方

Tags: unity3d

複数のNav Mesh Agentを作った時に，重ねる方法を教えてください。

例：
Player赤：Nav Mesh Agent
Player青：Nav Mesh Agent
のとき，Player赤の移動通路上にPlayer青がいたとしても，避けることなくすり抜けるようにしたい。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[マルチポスト](https://teratail.com/questions/40632)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のサイト（teratail）で解決できました。
https://teratail.com/questions/40632

> 未確認ですが、  NavMeshAgent の Priority を調整してみては如何でしょうか？
>
> 双方のQualityをNoneにしてみてください。
>   衝突回避せずに双方をすり抜けながら目的地に進みます。